# Unable to connect android application to parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to connect my android application to `parse.com` but I am stuck at last step.On Parse website it is mentioned Add the following to your ApplicationonCreate():

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

Parse.initialize(this, "yDdwwIjw0jmTnTEAzc3CQaXXXXXXXXXXXX", "kljfnAt3XXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

I am unable to understand how and where to add this code.Please guide through the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Create `Application` class inside main package

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, getString(R.string.parse_app_id), getString(R.string.parse_client_key));

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add permissions to your Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Create a class which extends the Application class

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, getString(R.string.parse_application_id), getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `android:name=".MyApp"` to the application in your Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".MyApp" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```